# Is there a way to transfer SMS mesages from a Samsung Galaxy S5) to an Ubuntu PC, in a form in which I can view the SMS messages on my PC?

Tags: sms, linux, samsung-galaxy-s-5, android-pc

I want to transfer the SMS messages on my Samsung Galaxy S5 smartphone to my PC (with Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS), in a form in which I can open and view the messages on my PC as I do on my smartphone.

I know about the apps which can back up smartphone data, such as Kies and Smart Switch for Samsung phones and ADB and Android File Transfer for Android devices. But as far as I can tell, these only back the SMS data up rather than save them as files which can be opened on PC desktop.

Comment: Many SMS backup apps backup to `xml` or `csv` file. Both are plain text formats.